# Decoding events with Rust

Tags: rpc, events, scale-codec

If I make a request to get events in a particular block using web UI, I get a nice human-readable response:

[image]

I've made an RPC call to get the same data

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "state_getStorageAt", 
    "params": ["0x26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef780d41e5e16056765bc8461851072c9d7","0x5056c4cb701e192962e5a76c895273e69188edea1badf9b145b884a9416c8443"]
}
```

... and I got an output

```json
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": "0x1000000000000000585f8f090000000002000000010000000508ba6ef6480a2c4173bbbf0c27355c0e3c6d7a874a21cc2464e97d3fd5d92e245b1b5a7307000000000000000000000000000001000000080380eb30ca364f5c349d573b62cfadadba95af2e94f62fd8af4e15b90b971a4da633803b0648373051a1e2158c547112dcf63802d0d52b301a33dae8b9c6114e90f012b8516d57525358775a7476385956586574346e43424a396776646d4a6e3564364b34385a6a6148704763515a75676300000100000000001027000000000000000000",
    "id": 1
}
```

I understand that it is a set of data encrypted with SCALE codec.

For example `0803` is a pallet and method indexes and
`eb30ca364f5c349d573b62cfadadba95af2e94f62fd8af4e15b90b971a4da633` is attached data.

What is the best way to decode the complete result with Rust? Thanks

### UPDATE

In the end this worked for me

```rust
#[subxt::subxt(runtime_metadata_path = "metadata.scale")]
pub mod polkadot {}

let data = "0x0c00000000000000585f8f090000000002000000010000000508ba6ef6480a2c4173bbbf0c27355c0e3c6d7a874a21cc2464e97d3fd5d92e245bd859730700000000000000000000000000000100000000010308011027000000000000000000";
let data_bytes = hex::decode(data.replace("0x", "")).unwrap();
let event = <polkadot::system::storage::Events as StorageEntry>::Value::decode(&mut data_bytes.as_slice()).unwrap();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two ways of decoding events in rust: statically typed and dynamically typed.

Statically you can use subxt to decode events from this SCALE encoding - it's done [here](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/master/examples/examples/subscribe_all_events.rs) for example. Basically every runtime has a concrete Event type and that's what you're decoding into.

```
let event_bytes = hex::decode("0x1000000000000000585f8f090000000002000000010000000508ba6ef6480a2c4173bbbf0c27355c0e3c6d7a874a21cc2464e97d3fd5d92e245b1b5a7307000000000000000000000000000001000000080380eb30ca364f5c349d573b62cfadadba95af2e94f62fd8af4e15b90b971a4da633803b0648373051a1e2158c547112dcf63802d0d52b301a33dae8b9c6114e90f012b8516d57525358775a7476385956586574346e43424a396776646d4a6e3564364b34385a6a6148704763515a75676300000100000000001027000000000000000000").unwrap();
let event = <polkadot::Event as Decode>::decode(&mut event_bytes.as_slice()).unwrap();
```

and I have polkadot defined as:

```
#[subxt::subxt(runtime_metadata_path = "polkadot_metadata.scale")]
pub mod polkadot {}
```

(rather than pointing it at a metadata file you can download it by giving it a url `#[subxt::subxt(runtime_metadata_path = "wss://kusama-rpc.polkadot.io:443")]`. If you point that at your node's url then it should decode your event.)

Dynamically the tooling needs generalising, but [it is possible](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/blob/1dab046b73bb06425962435bc1d397fc480c4b89/src/cmd/extrinsics/events.rs#L61) and has been done by cargo-contract.

If you need to interpret all events across all parachains then go dynamic. If you are focused on a few particular parachains then static typing is a lot safer and easier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there an option to decode it using `parity_scale_codec::Decode`? If I understand correctly `Decode` is just a Trait and I need pre-defined `Struct` to use it. Where can I find the structure of an event?

Comment: The above are all using that `Decode` trait but the key is that you need to give it the type to re-hydrate (to deserialise into). That's the `Event` type that is defined on the runtime associated with the parachain / relay chain that your decoding the event for.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My solution was based on your answer